# Syntax error on pagination

Tags: php, mysql, pagination

This should be a fairly straight forward question. I am getting a `Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean` error and I can't figure out the correct syntax. Using mysqlerror I am getting `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '-5, 5'` .

Any help would be great. The code is part of a pagination that I am adding.

**Snippet of affected code**

```
<?php
//Number of items to display per page  
$perpage = 5;

if(isset($_GET["page"]))
{
    $page = intval($_GET["page"]);
}
else
{
    $page = 1;
}

$calc = $perpage * $page;
$start = $calc - $perpage;
$result = mysql_query("select * from products Limit $start, $perpage");
$rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
echo mysql_error();

if($rows)
{
    $i = 0;
    while($post = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
?>
```

Comment: You should check `mysql_error` immediately after you run `mysql_query`.

Comment: Side tip: You should leave pagination efforts for client side code like Javascript to lower the work the server has to do.

Comment: @Dave and _drastically_ increase the amount of work the browser has to do?  It's fine client-side with a few dozen or maybe a few hundred rows, can result in a terrible user experience above that.  The RDBMS is already optimized for this work. Not to mention the bandwidth of sending all the paginated rows to the client.

Comment: @Dave - Really? I see pagination nearly *always* computed in server side code. Paginating hundreds of items, means loading them ALL with each page - and processing them in browser upon each page load. Not good for Bandwith, Not good for User Experience.

Comment: Additionally: forget the ```mysql_*``` functions; *ext/mysql* is a deprecated API as of PHP 5.5 - so it's a really good idea to use mysqli or PDO.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski i would rather hardware supported browsers do the work once for that person, than a server doing say perhaps 100k users requesting every day. There will still need to be some SQL efforts with using LIMIT. But i wouldn't do the maths server side, id just send a request from JS with the range of rows needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$start cannot be negative (and it is). You should make sure, that $page is not less than 1. This should fix your problem:

```
<?php
 //Number of items to display per page  
 $perpage = 5;
 $page = isset($_GET['page']) ? intval($_GET['page']) : 1;
 if ($page < 1)
 {
   $page = 1;
 }
 $calc = $perpage * $page;
 $start = $calc - $perpage;
 $result = mysql_query("select * from products Limit $start, $perpage");
 $rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
 echo mysql_error();
 if($rows)
 {
  $i = 0;
  while($post = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
?>
```

Comment: Why throw the extra if-statement in there? I think you goofed your code up a little bit.

Comment: @Josh Brody - Because you need to check if page parameter was greater or equal 1. Without that if, this code will break if someone passes ?page=0 or ?page=-1

Comment: Perfect. Worked like a charm. THanks

Comment: @Woljciech Zylinski I would just call abs() to get the absolute value of the number. Less logic.

Comment: On another note I'm linking the pagination numbers at the bottom using 'admin.master.php?page=list_products.php&page=$i' but its producing a error. Whats the correct way to link this as its in a master php format?

Comment: I'd call the links like <a href="admin.master.php?page=list_products.php&page=<?=$i?>"><?=$i?></a>

Comment: What's the error? You can print page links with a simple loop: for ($i = 1; $i <= $totalPages; $i++) { echo '<a href="admin.master.php?page=list_products.php&page=' . $i . '">' . $i . '</a> '; }

Answer (score 2):

when you're using `LIMIT` the value of the starting point should be greater or equal to zero.

- [LIMIT](http://php.about.com/od/mysqlcommands/g/Limit_sql.htm)